# Javascript div output in html not working

Tags: javascript, html, output, innerhtml

I am using this innerhtml property to print my output from javascript into a div in html. I have checked other topics with the same problem, but nothing seems to work.

The following code is all between the 'body' tags in my html.

**Code:**

```
<script> function firstGame(); </script>

<div id="outputgame"> </div>
<button onclick="functionGame()"> Starten </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function firstGame()
    {
        var output = document.getElementById('outputgame');
        output.innerHTML('<p>First test</p>');

        // Check if the user is ready to play!
        confirm("Are you ready to play this epic game?")

        var age = prompt("What is your age?");
        if (age < 13)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML= "You are to young to play this  game. You can proceed, however i do not take any responsibility";

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML= "Sweet, Let's go!";
        }
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you got a reference to jQuery in the head?

Comment: Your call to `firstGame()` happens in a different script block then the function is. So when calling upon `firstGame` a script error is returned since `firstGame` isn't defined. Move the call to the second script block.

Comment: You dont need jQuery...

Comment: Please delete the confirm since it clearly not necessary and utterly annoying.

Comment: wrap your prompt in a parseInt(prompt("What is your age?"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk about page rendering upon initialization and `global scope`. *A scope is the context in which values and expressions are "visible," or can be referenced*. `The global scope` is the context for the whole `document`. If a value or function is declared here it's visible in every function or expression.

The JavaScript in your page is being parsed one script block at a time. When the script block is parsed without errors the script block is transferred into the global scope. The thread (stored in the window object) where all public values and expressions are available.

Functions are parsed first, then the rest of the block. However script blocks are parsed one at a time I wrote earlier. So if you make a call to a function not yet in the global scope since it's in another script block that hasn't been parsed yet your code will fail and throw and undefined error.

Consider this:

```
 <script>
     function test()
     {
         alert(1);
     }
     test();
 </script>
```

A nice alert is shown. the function `test` is parsed first and `test` is executed thereafter.

```
 <script>
     test();
     function test()
     {
         alert(1);
     }

 </script>
```

This also works. Since functions are parsed first `test()` still works and alerts `1`.

```
 <script>
     test();
 </script>
 <script>
     function test()
     {
         alert(1);
     }

 </script>
```

This however won't work. Since the function `test` in the second script block isn't yet parsed calling `test()` will result in a script error.

```
 <script>
     function test()
     {
         alert(1);
     }

 </script>
 <script>
     test();
 </script>
```

This does work. The function is declared first and added to the global scope. In the second script block `test()` looks for a function `test` in the `global scope`, finds it and executes it.

This is the explanation above applied to your code:

```
<div id="outputgame"> </div>
<button onclick="functionGame()"> Starten </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function firstGame()
    {
        var output = document.getElementById('outputgame');
        output.innerHTML = '<p>First test</p>';

        // Check if the user is ready to play!
        // Do you really need this?
        //Confirm returns a Boolean (true or false), you can do something with the result. If not just show an alert or nothing. Latter is preferred. 
        confirm("Are you ready to play this epic game?")

        var age = prompt("What is your age?");
        //You should make this more robust. What if someone enters "asaaslk". Use a select box with birth years.
        if (age < 13)
        {
            document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML = "You are to young to play this  game. You can proceed, however i do not take any responsibility";

        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML = "Sweet, Let's go!";
        }
     }
 </script>
 <script> function firstGame(); </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I am just starting out with javascript and had no idea that JavaScript is being parsed one script block at a time. However it does make sense.

Oh and about the confirm thing: this was just an exercise I made out some basic stuff from javascript, but I could not get it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <div id="outputgame"> </div>
        <button onclick="firstGame()"> Starten </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function firstGame()
        {
            var output = document.getElementById('outputgame');

            output.innerHTML = '<p>First test</p>';

            // Check if the user is ready to play!
            confirm("Are you ready to play this epic game?")

            var age = prompt("What is your age?");
            if (age < 13)
            {
                document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML= "You are to young to play this  game. You can proceed, however i do not take any responsibility";

            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML= "Sweet, Let's go!";
            }
         }
         </script>
```

Comment: Code–only answers are not liked. You should explain why the OP has the issue and why your answer fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: You named your function the wrong name?, and you are calling `innerHTML` as a function instead of assigning it a value.

Also, where is `functionGame()` defined? You cannot use forward declarations like in C.

```js
function firstGame() {
  var output = document.getElementById('outputgame');
  var text = '';
  output.innerHTML = '<p>First test</p>';

  // Check if the user is ready to play!
  confirm("Are you ready to play this epic game?")

  var age = parseInt(prompt("What is your age?"), 10);
  if (age < 13) {
    text = "You are to young to play this game. You can proceed, however I do not take any responsibility.";
  } else {
    text = "Sweet, Let's go!";
  }

  document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div id="outputgame"></div>
<button onclick="firstGame()">Starten</button>
```

Comment: I don't think the button is used to fire the function `firstGame()`. I think this has to happen on initialisation and then the user can start the game by pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="outputgame"> </div>
<button onclick="firstGame()"> Starten </button>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function firstGame()
{
var output = document.getElementById('outputgame');
output.innerHTML='<p>First test</p>';

// Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("Are you ready to play this epic game?")

var age = prompt("What is your age?");
if (age < 13)
{
document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML= "You are to young to play this  game.You can proceed, however i do not take any responsibility";

}
else
{
    document.getElementById('outputgame').innerHTML= "Sweet, Let's go!";
}
}

</script>
```